# SharePoint 2010 ListData.svc REST API Randomly returns error: 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI from HTTPClient

Tags: c#, sharepoint, .net-core, sharepoint-2010, dotnet-httpclient

I'm experiencing an intermittent problem with our SharePoint 2010 REST API. I have a .Net Core Console application that makes a series of calls to SharePoint List Endpoints to get a JSON response. My problem is that at random times, the API response is an error page:

> A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter
>   represents an absolute URI.http://www.example.com/somefolder/file.svc

Is there a problem with my HTTPClient configuration? Is there a configuration setting that I can toggle in SharePoint to prevent the error or more reliable?

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/");
var credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { uri, "NTLM", credential } };
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(handler);
Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.com/sharepoint/path/ListData.svc/");



// Make the list request
var result = await Client.GetAsync("MySharePointList");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the list items, the REST API URI like below.

```
http://sp2010/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/listname
```

Modify the code as below.

```
var siteUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
var listName = "MySharePointList";
var uri = new Uri(siteUrl);
var credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { uri, "NTLM", credential } };
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri, "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc");       
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json;odata=verbose");
var requestURL = siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" + listName;
// Make the list request
var result = client.GetAsync(requestURL).Result;
var items= result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did implement your code. I wasn't sure if the addition/omission of a trailing slash on the .svc segment would have an impact so I was sure to mirror your values. I'm still getting the errors. Are you aware of anything else I can try  - or any configurations I may want to verify?